# DayOfYear function in T-SQL / SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

2 FEB is the 33rd day of the year, for example.

Is there a built-in T-SQL function that returns the day-of-year (in SQL Server 2000)?  Or do you have to roll your own using casts to get the first day of the year for the supplied date, and then do a DateDiff?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
SELECT datepart(dayofyear, getdate())
```